# Can I define a macro that defines macros ?

Tags: c++, macros

The question came to mind by looking at the memory leak detection mechanism in VS. There the following boilerplate code is needed :

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
```

but replacing this code with `DETECT_MLEAKS` :

```
#define DETECT_MLEAKS\
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC\
#include <stdlib.h>\
#include <crtdbg.h>\
```

can't be done.

Are there any workarounds - suggestions ?

Comment: You could put those lines (and an include guard) in detect_memleaks.h and do `#include "detect_memleaks.h"` instead...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the standard C language, macros cannot generate preprocessing directives. For instance in the ISO 9899:1999 standard:

> 6.10.3.4 Rescanning and further replacement
>
> [ ... ]
>
> The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed
> as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one, [ ... ]

(This "even if it resembles one" remark is completely superfluous because, of course, no syntax is ever treated as a preprocessing directive if it does **not** resemble one! Yet, the words stick in your mind for years. I just located the quote's section by searching the document for the string "resembles one".)

Answer (score 6):

```
//#define DETECT_MLEAKS //Uncomment to detect mem-leaks
#ifdef DETECT_MLEAKS
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#endif
```

Is how I typically do such things.